Why does my npx plop function can't find my plopfile?
I'm building a npx package to generate React apps boilerplates. For this I'm using Plop.js. The CLI works when I'm in inside the package's folder, but if I run the npx command outside it returns this error:
[PLOP] No plopfile found

The command I'm using is:
npx julseb-plop-utils

You can find the github repo here https://github.com/JulSeb42/julseb-plop-utils, and the npm package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/julseb-plop-utils
Thanks!
